# Accessing another property from another function

Tags: javascript

I'm using Gsap to create nice animations.

I'm on the verge of making bad Javascript here and would appreciate some help.

```
let navOpen = false;

const navAnim = () => {
  var tl = gsap.timeline({})
  tl.to(nav, 1, { x: 0, y: 0, z: 0 });
}

const checkNavigation = () => {
  navOpen ? navAnim.tl.play() : navAnim.tl.reverse()
}

const navigation = () => {
  if (!navOpen) {
    navOpen = true;
    checkNavigation();
  } else {
    navOpen = false;
    checkNavigation();
  }
}

navBrgr.addEventListener("click", () => {
  navigation();
});
```

The function to open the Navigation simply creates a new timeline and then executes the code inside.

To close my navigation, it needs to do exactly the same but this time reverse it.

My code at the moment leads to `Cannot read property 'play' of undefined` which does make sense because I can't access `tl` from this `navigation();` function. How can I do so?

I was stupid enough to think a `return()` inside of my `navAnim()` would suffice, alas.

Many thanks

Comment: `navAnim ` is a function which does not return anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that `navAnim` returns `tl` so that you can use that value in your `checkNavigation` function.

Update your `navAnim` and `checkNavigation` functions to the following:

```
const navAnim = () => {
  var tl = gsap.timeline({})
  tl.to(nav, 1, { x: 0, y: 0, z: 0 });
  return tl
}

const checkNavigation = () => {
  const tl = navAnim()
  navOpen ? tl.play() : tl.reverse()
}
```

That should do the trick.

---

### Cleaner Code Recommendation:

```
let navOpen = false;
const tl = gsap.timeline({})
tl.to(nav, 1, { x: 0, y: 0, z: 0 });

const toggleNav() {
  navOpen = !navOpen
  if (navOpen) tl.play()
  else tl.reverse()
}

navBrgr.addEventListener("click", () => {
  toggleNav();
});
```

This prevents creating a bunch of functions that can be solved with simple one liners.